# writing html tags & css in code behind C#

Tags: c#

can somebody advise writing code the below way, is it a good practice?

```
this.ltlTtlRes.Text = string.Format("<span>{0}</span>", oComp.Emls.Count().ToString());
```

currently im reviewing code, and I am finding such html in code behind, not sure if it is a good practice, can somebody advise?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: hard to tell from that tiny code fragment. If the `this.ltlTtlRes` variable is used inside a templated html solution its fine, otherwhise it would be a better/maintanable approach to do so ( eg https://github.com/jagregory/docu/tree/master )

Comment: The code won't be a bad thing I suppose. It would be better if you used literal controls to render the html to page. The innerHtml property of the HtmlGenericControl class will also do.

Comment: I don't see any thing wrong with this code....

Comment: I don't suppose there is anything particularly "wrong" with the code. But it doesn't sit well with me personally. To me it kinda muddies the water between code and markup. I prefer to see the markup being output on the aspx page rather than in a codebehind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this stuff, the .Net library contains something called a `HttpTextWriter`, and comes with many stuff to nicely balance tags, escape content, etc.

http://revenmerchantservices.com/post/C-HtmlTextWriter-Example.aspx

Althought using this class is a little verbose, please think again about the possible issues with script injection or such. You can always write a little wrapper method.

PS.

```
oComp.Emls.Count().ToString()
```

Leave out the `.ToString()`. string.Format is very well capable to format the number with the {0} placeholder. Check string.Format formatting numbers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx